# Identify this fruit?

Tags: identification

I saw these in Florida. I’m not sure if it’s a fruit, but it looks like a miniature pumpkin:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is a dracena, but very difficult to find which one. Closest match is the *Dracaena afromontana* which is an African plant, shown in my photo. I have not been able to find evidence of one with bicolored leaves with this size and presentation of fruit. But this is certainly an exact match for growth pattern, note how the fruiting branches are characteristically leafless, as are the ones in your photo. The *Dracena reflexa* has similar leaves, but the fruit is not the same. There are well over 100 species of *Dracena*, and more cultivars are developed all the time, so exact identification may be difficult. So many plants manage to "hitchhike" into Florida, discovering it's origin and family tree are very difficult. The link to the site this photo is from is:
http://www.africanplants.senckenberg.de/root/index.php?page_id=78&id=3559
 [image]

Comment: Is this an edible fruit? Thanks for your answer.